# Regular Expressions in C++ using Boost

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

So far.. I have this test string:

```
Hello {John|Paul|Cindy}, hows {david}?
```

and my expression is:

```
(\{\w+\})
```

However, it only returns david. I want to be able to grab John, Paul, and Cindy. 
There would only be 0 or 2 vertical bars. any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: \w matches a normal charakter. But | is none. Therefore it matches only {david}. {John|Paul|Cindy} is not matched because it contains symbols | that are not contained in \w. But I am not sure what you want to achive?

Comment: yes I see that, I want to just grab all of the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not some kind of competition, I would simply use two regular expressions:

`{[\w|]+}` to grab each pair of curly brackets along with its content, then, on each result, `\w+` to extract words.

You can't go simpler using just one regex.

Answer (score 1):

If only 0 or 2 vertical bars:

```
(\{\w+\}|\{\w+\|\w+\|\w+\})
```

For 0 or more:

```
(\{\w+(\|\w+)*\})
```

Comment: your first answer only grabs the first name

Comment: i'm using http://www.rubular.com/ if you want to check the string above with your expression.

Comment: Yeah i make a mistake. Anyway better to edit comment, then to post twice.

Comment: Here's another version for 0, 1 or 2: `(\{\w+\|{0,1}\w+\|{0,1}\w+\})` (Maybe you don't want to pick up when its only 1 vertical bar though).